# java command not found in terminal

Tags: java, terminal

I am trying to use [deck2pdf](https://github.com/melix/deck2pdf) which is a java program to make pdf out of javascript slides presentation.

I followed the installation process from github:

1. cloned the repo
2. made `./gradlew distZip` which generated a .zip file in `build/distributions/`
3. unizpped this file `deck2pdf-0.2-SNAPSHOT.zip` in my JS project folder

this folder has the following content:

```
- deck2pdf-0.2-SNAPSHOT
    - bin
        - deck2pdf
        - deck2pdf.bat
    - lib
        - deck2pdf-0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
        - groovy-2.3.2.jar
        - itextpdf-5.5.1.jar
        - jfxrt.jar
```

then, I call `deck2pdf` in the terminal from my project folder, 
but it says : `command not found`

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have Java installed? Try to type `java -h` into your terminal. What is the result? If Java cannot be found, you might have to modify your System's `Path` variable and add Java.

Comment: @ClaasWilke `java -h` displays the manual. when I do `java -version` i have `java version "1.8.0_11"`. In the path i added this: `export JAVA_HOME="/usr/libexec/java_home"`. should i do something else?

Comment: @tim_yates did you downvote? is there something wrong in this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

`deck2pdf`

You need to run

`./deck2pdf`

Comment: this says: `-bash: ./deck2pdf: is a directory`, and nothing happens

Comment: finally… it's working… almost. the generated pdf is just blank pages, but at least there is something happening. thank you.